# Question on a deleted question, google's cache and SE betas...

Tags: support, deleted-questions

As I opened my account today I found:

[image]

hmm, ok. I tried to have a look at it, [without success](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/101616/fourier-transform-inverse-of-a-heavside-function). Ok that was expected.

Then I tried the Advanced Ninja Search, resp the [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:math.stackexchange.com/questions+Fourier+transform+%28inverse%29+of+a+Heavside+function).
The question was still [in the cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ZGOLh9r5Mq4J:math.stackexchange.com/questions/101616/fourier-transform-inverse-of-a-heavside-function+&cd=2&hl=de&ct=clnk).
Here it's also obvious, that I lost 2 reps due to the suggested edit.

Now there are several options:

4. This Google search "feature" doesn't seem to work on questions at StackExchanges that are in `beta`. Why is that?
5. You can anonymously give feedback. Where does this go? For not deleted questions, it's counted in the database, but this question is deleted. So what happens with the feedback? **Remark** You can't vote up/down or favor the question, since your not logged in and logging will lead you away from this question.
6. You can `improve the question`. Clicking this opens the nominal edit page, where I can `Save Edits`. Will this undelete the question?
   I'm scientist, so if nobody would get hurt I would click it, but Jose might have had his reasons to delete the question...
7. and last, but least: Jose, why did you delete it?

Sorry for posting more than one question, but I think they are all quite related...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Generally, searches are blocked by the "robots.txt" file on the server. For example questions on [Anime and Manga beta](https://anime.stackexchange.com/) fall under the restrictions in [this file](https://anime.stackexchange.com/robots.txt). I don't see any restrictions that would keep Google's webcrawler from searching the questions and answers from that site. Perhaps I am missing something.
2. When a question or answer has been deleted, attempting to upvote/downvote usually displays this message:
   [image]
3. Deleted questions can be edited (if one has the privileges to do so). The edit page that the page cache brings up looks like the one presented to guests, which is then submitted as a suggested edit for review by other users.  Apparently, this does not work for deleted questions or answers.
4. Asaf is correct; questions with no votes or activity for a year are automatically deleted. If deemed beneficial, a moderator can undelete a question or answer.

Comment: Whoa, SE blocks Yahoo from crawling all their sites, including StackOverflow.

Comment: @5PM [Here's an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53502).

Answer (score 3):

Let me answer the fourth question.

The question was deleted because it had zero votes and zero activity for a year now. This happens automatically.

Let me also speculate about the third question, those are scripts embedded into the page which is cached and therefore you can run them. None of these things would have much effect, I believe.

Comment: ahh thanks for the 'zero activity for a year' thing  and correct: `saving edit` didn't work. +1...

Comment: Mmm, I did not know that, but I have a doubt: what it means "zero activity"? no visits from an IP? no answer in a year?

Comment: @dwarandae From [How can a post be deleted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/206169): The system will automatically delete unlocked, unanswered questions with score of zero (or one if the owner is deleted), fewer than 1.5 views per day on average, and fewer than two comments after a 365 days.